# "Featured question" bug

Tags: bug

Questions seem to be staying in the "featured" tab for too long. This previously happened with [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/9090/3555) and now with [this one](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/22824/3555). In both cases the bounty expired and yet the question remained "featured".  I think it may have been when another bounty was started that the first question finally got bumped out of the "featured" list, but that may have just been when I noticed it.

Thank you to the flagger-who-shall-remain-anonymous who pointed this out the first time around.

Comment: [Visual illustration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ftZpT.png).

Comment: I noticed this elsewhere but assumed that the system was simply featuring the question for seven days regardless of when the bounty was awarded.  Not sure if that explains it here, however.

Comment: @Nathaniel Interesting... elsewhere on another beta site? I wasn't sure whether to assume it was broader than a BH.SE issue, but it seems likely. In this case the bounty is long gone....expired....evaporated, even.

Comment: Originally I was thinking of Latin.SE, but we also have an instance of this on Christianity right now.  My explanation might make sense there (bounty not scheduled to end for a few more hours) but not here.  And both cases seem to go against [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/300411) ("Questions with **an active bounty**... are also visible on the home page's Featured tab.")  So this smells like an MSE-worthy bug.

Comment: @Nathaniel My impression is that the appropriate SE people check out the [meta-tag:bug]s on all of the meta sites, and I suppose if it is a bug and not previously reported they would figure out whether it applied to other sites.

Comment: You're probably right, but an MSE post wouldn't hurt given that we now have clear evidence of this on both C.SE and BH.SE.  I've put together screenshots and posted on MSE: [Questions with ended bounties are not being removed from the “featured” tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281760/300411)

Comment: This has been fixed, per Marc Gravell on MSE: [Questions with ended bounties are not being removed from the “featured” tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283722/300411).